# XCode 8 updates in Provisioning Profile not reflected

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, provisioning-profile

I'm using **Automatic Provisioning Profile** in XCode 8.
The problem is after adding new devices from the [developer console](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/), the changes are not reflected in the XCode provisioning profile.

Where as if I try to run a project on a new device using a usb, the XCode prompts whether to add this device to profile & then it updates the profile but **NOT** when **adding a device from [developer console](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/)**.

In the earlier versions the profiles were **not automatically managed** & I could just **overwrite the updated profile** by downloading it from server but this is not the case now.

Also **enabling/disabling devices** from console doesn't work.

Comment: I believe if you are using automatic code signing, Xcode expects all changes to the profile to be done from Xcode.  You shouldn't be trying to manually manage the profiles from the developer console.

Comment: I understand but I had to add a device for testing & I didn't had that with me. I added UUID from the developer console. Anyway I found the solution. I deleted the existing profiles on the mac & the XCode automatically downloaded the new/updated profile from the server/(developer site)/

Comment: The profiles are not automatically downloaded to your mac if you make changes on the developer site.  Any time you change anything about the profile (device ID changes / cert changes / entitlements), you need to re-download the profile on your Mac.   Xcode has always worked that way unless you did automatic code signing.  You are not.  You are selecting Xcode to automatically choose the profile that best fits from those you've downloaded on your Mac.

Comment: @wottle I figured it out eventually. Many thanks for the detailed answer & I think they should put it in the docs, I was going nuts searching for solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Delete the existing provisioning profile from location
   *~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles*
2. Open the project & use the automatic profiling option & XCode will pull the new/changes to profile from the server(developer.apple.com)